# What does Adjective, Verb, Noun, or Adverb mean?

Tags: meaning

I don't know what it means.
It confusing me like it says noun is used before an adjective.

It's so confusing and troublesome.

Take a look:

- *Noun*: a word that refers to a person, place, thing, event, substance or quality e.g.'nurse', 'cat', 'party', 'oil' and 'poverty'.
- *Verb*: a word or phrase that describes an action, condition or experience e.g. 'run', 'look' and 'feel'.
- *Adjective*: a word that describes a noun e.g. 'big', 'boring', 'pink', 'quick' and 'obvious'.

Comment: Your are asking about things known as the "parts of speech". [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_grammar#Parts_of_speech) is once place you can look for information about them. However, since they are very basic for talking about English sentences and grammar, they are probably better explained by someone teaching you in person.

Comment: @Araucaria That "rubbish article" _is_ the canonical answer. But I don't think concepts like these (in any terminology) can be taught by definitions, not even definitions with a few accompanying examples. For most people, learning them requires some patient, in-person interaction, as well as getting some experience with the language so you can understand what the concepts abstract from.

Comment: It starts off with "*nouns are things*" the very epitomy of bad grammar teaching!!! And *EXACTLY* the reason why the OP had to ask this question here. What kind of "thing" is *arrival* or *massacre*?

Comment: @BenKovitz Something is a compound made up of the words *some* and *thing*. Underneath common noun it says: "*refers to something abstract: a kind of object (table, radio), a kind of living thing (cat, person), a kind of place (home, city), a kind of action (running, laughter, extinction), a kind of attribute (redness, size), a kind of relationship (closeness, partnership), or anything at all, no matter how abstract (two, god, diversity, corporation*" (which doesn't describe the difference between for example, a noun or a verb or an adjective ...

Comment: @BenKovitz ... further on it defines adjectives as "*words that describe nouns"*.  So, erm, how does that fit with "*boy is it hot*". What noun is "*hot*" describing there? And under pronouns it says that a pronoun is a word that is used in place of a noun. However, that would seem to apply to the common noun *one*, as in "*I'd like  the blue ones please*". Or the words *thing* or *stuff*. More importantly, what noun is *it* replacing in "*It's important to be there on time*". There's no noun that we could substitute in there without changing the meaning ...

Comment: @BenKovitz ... Under verbs, it says that they signify the predicate of a sentence. However, in "*to err is human*", the verb "*ERR*" is part of the subject, not the predicate! IIt also says that verbs form part of what is asserted by a sentence, this is not true of verbs in subordinate clauses. It defines adverbs thus: "*An adverb modifies a verb, an adjective, other adverbs, or the whole sentence*". So under this definition "*Alomost*" isn't an adverb in "*Almost a third of the sample*", nor "*right*" in "*right over the top*". I shall stop there for the time being ... :(

Comment: @BenKovitz Although I do concede that at least it points out that nouns can refer to actions, which is definitely a plus 1.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks for the long and thoughtful answer. I think, though, that comments are too hard a forum to discuss the problems with traditional grammar—which I certainly agree has severe flaws when applied to English. My point here is just that, right or wrong, like it or not, in ordinary usage, meanings of "noun", "verb", etc. are the concepts of traditional grammar.

Comment: @BenKovitz Just because these daft definitions are on a Wiki page under "traditional grammar" don't mean that traditional grammar only has daft definitions! :) There are plenty of traditional grammars without silly definitions for these things. Just not that many on the web! We need to look in real books!! This question needs an answer - in fact lots of them :-)

Comment: @Araucaria I think it would be awesome if you wanted to contribute a canonical post and I would hope that you would write a clearer question than this one (or its duplicate http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53630/9161) to start if off. A question written by someone who understands the issue would probably be easier for learners to find in a search, and could be framed in a way to make the answer clearer.

Comment: @Araucaria Thanks for the suggestions for sources. I do think that the Wikipedia article needs a lot of work, and I took no offense. It's a collaborative work, anyway: I just modified what was already there, and there are many parts I don't like. The article is on traditional grammar generally: the way of thinking about grammar, with "eight parts of speech", that started in Ancient Greece, and was basically force-fit onto English.

Comment: @Araucaria Looks like we both noticed the same thing (the Wikipedia article isn't just about English). I think it probably needs a total rewrite.

Comment: @BenKovitz The way to get round the noun problem, for example, is just to say, "*Nouns* are words that very often denote objects, (eg, ......), but they can also describe, for example, abstract ideas, actions ..." and so forth. Then go on to describe the syntactic properties of nouns. Noun is a syntactic idea, really, not a semantic one. ( - sorry, that's an old comment that I forgot to post!)

Comment: @Araucaria Hmm, I just took a look at the IGE, and it doesn't look very traditional to me. I think the long-lasting appeal of traditional grammar, even though it clashes with English, is its simplicity and intuitiveness. In this U.S., it's taught in the first grade—to six-year-olds! One doesn't tell a 6yo "An adjective is an open word class which expresses an attribute. The attribute is expressed either by an attributive adjective (_a **red** car_) or by a predicative adjective (_my car is **red**_)." Well, I'll track down some solid information about it (once I finish my "real" work).

Comment: @Araucaria BTW, the traditional definition of noun (copied and recopied since Dionysius Thrax in ~100 B.C.) is "a name for either a tangible or an abstract thing, meant either specifically or generally, which has case and number"—almost exactly what you're saying, and also what's in the Wikipedia article. The "tangible or abstract" phrasing started in opposition to the Stoic theory of grammar, which claimed that it was only meaningful to talk about tangible things. This was already argued out 2,000 years ago, to the same conclusion! :) _Vide etiam_ http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ViolentAgreement

Comment: @Araucaria So you're going to write a monograph for us all readers? You gonna be explaining the difference between grammatical category and syntactic function? Is it gonna be a long rainy weekend? :)

Comment: @F.E. Hey, I was championing this so we could read one of your excellent and phenomenal posts! :)

Comment: @Araucaria It's just that the subject matter is probably way too, too, too broad. There are 300 page modern grammar textbooks written for college students (native English speakers), and those books are basically describing categories and functions, on the whole. It's probably better to just nibble on specific examples. Unless you're a glutton for punishment. Er, you are, aren't you? (That was a rhetorical question) -- I'm just here on a break from reviewing PPs.  :)

Comment: Portions of this conversation have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22478/discussion-on-question-by-shamboo-what-does-adjective-verb-noun-or-adverb-mea).

Answer (score 1):

Shamboo, I think I can give you a simple approach to help you get some intuitive understanding of these.  I have been helping my son learn these recently.

> it says noun is used before an adjective.

I'm not sure where you saw that, but you are right to feel confused about it!  It is incorrect.

For now, just think of a noun as a person, place or thing.  For example: *mother, house, dog*.  You can say *my mother, my forest, my dog*.  So, those are nouns.

Now let's do adjectives.  The adjective tells us, in a small number of words, what *kind* of noun the noun is.  Examples: *a strict mother, a big forest, a friendly dog.*

When you are looking at a sentence and you want to find the nouns, and the adjectives, please try to find words that seem similar to my examples.

*Verbs* can be a little harder to learn.  There are two kinds.  The first kind is a very small group of words.  The most common one is "to be (am, are, is, etc.)." for example, *She is hungry.*  This type of verb is similar to an equals sign: *She = hungry.*

The second kind of verb is an *action word.*  You have to use energy to do an action!  For example, *She runs. She thinks. She cooks.*

Verbs might *look* more complicated than that, for example *She ran.  She will think.  She was cooking.*  But it's still the same idea.

I hope this helps.